# How to get the Layout used by a partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have several Layout **(master pages)** in my project and I wanna do some conditions on shared Partial Pages based on the layout that these pages are using. Is there any way to get the the layout page that these partials are using?

So far I've tried:

```
@{
  if (Layout == "_MasterPage") //layout always come as NULL, even thought it is being used correctly
}
```

Is there any other way to check for the Layout used?

Answer (score 0):

> "Is there any other way to check for the Layout used?"

Yes, there is. 
You can use a specific model (and use regular OOP inheritance) and check in your partial, for instance.

<strike>Also, it feels like a hack, but nothing is stopping you from defining a cookie or something when using one master page or the other and checking that inside your partial.</strike>